# Liquibase knows port from application.properties (it connects to my database), but not ${port} in its changeset, until a <property> is set

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

At *Spring Boot* startup, a *Liquibase* changelog is executed from this `application.properties`:

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/comptesfrance
changeLogFile=../AdapterOutboundPostgis/target/classes/db/changelog/compte-france-postgis-changelog.xml
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
username=postgres
password=postgres
port=5434
```

The connection is done, each changeset is served, except for those of that kind:

```xml
<changeSet id="shp2pgsql_communes_2023" author="mlebihan" failOnError="false">
    <comment>Importation des shapefiles des contours des communes 2023</comment>

    <executeCommand executable="/bin/bash">
        <arg value="-c"/>
        <arg value="export PGPASSWORD=${password};shp2pgsql -s 4326 
           -I /data/comptes-france/territoire/2023/communes.shp public.communes_2023 | 
           psql -d comptesfrance -U postgres -h localhost -p ${port} -q"/>
    </executeCommand>
</changeSet>
```

Here, `${password}` and `${port}` aren't resolved.

```bash
/bin/bash -c export PGPASSWORD=${password};shp2pgsql -s 4326 
   -I /data/comptes-france/territoire/2023/communes.shp public.communes_2023 | 
   psql -d comptesfrance -U postgres -h localhost -p ${port} -q
```

I've tried to add a property `liquibase.port=5434` in my property file, but without success.

As a workaround I've sat at the top of my changelog:

```xml
<property name="port" value="5434" />
<property name="password" value="postgres" />
```

and then, it works. I can see:

```bash
Shell command '/bin/bash -c export PGPASSWORD=postgres;shp2pgsql -s 4326 
    -I /data/comptes-france/territoire/2023/communes.shp public.communes_2023 | 
    psql -d comptesfrance -U postgres -h localhost -p 5434 -q' executed
```

But this cannot stand for long.

Why `application.properties` *Spring Boot* parameters can be interpreted by *Liquibase* - because it can connect to the database (on a non standard *Postgresql* port: `5434`) - and not be found for the changelogs/changesets at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot defines Liquibase (LB) properties under it's own perfix `spring.liquibase`. If you'd like to pass parameters to the LB you should have something like this:

```
spring.liquibase.parameters.port=5434
spring.liquibase.parameters.password=postgres
```